# My headsetmic(astro A40) doesn't show up on the settings 20.4

Tags: microphone, settings, system-settings

i installed Ubuntu after my Windows had a complete breakdown and everything was fine and all, but when i installed discord i noticed, that my microphone wasn't enabled so i went to the system settings and... nothing my mic is nowhere to be found.
does anyone know how to fix that?
I would really appreciate any help
.

Comment: It sounds to me like this microphone may not be compatible with Linux: https://www.reddit.com/r/AstroGaming/comments/gqywx4/a40_mixamp_pro_microphone_and_dual_output_on_linux/